# access sql inner join and count in 2 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a question about sql queries in access (i just started like 3 days ago)

so there are 2 tables: employes and departments, what i want is to create a query which will show the name and id of each employe and how many departments he manages.

```
Employee( ID, NAME, social_security_of_employe)

Department(department_id, social_security_of_employee)
```

(social security is my primary key)
my try was:

```
SELECT E.ID, E.NAME, COUNT(D.SOCIAL_SECURITY) AS NUMBER_OF_DEPARTMENTS

FROM EMPLOYEE E

INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D

WHERE D.SOCIAL_SECURITY=E.SOCIAL_SECURITY

GROUP BY SOCIAL_SECURITY
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for MS Access is:

```
SELECT E.ID, E.NAME, COUNT(D.SOCIAL_SECURITY) AS NUMBER_OF_DEPARTMENTS
FROM EMPLOYEE as E INNER JOIN
     DEPARTMENT as D
     ON D.SOCIAL_SECURITY = E.SOCIAL_SECURITY
GROUP BY E.ID, E.NAME;
```

Changes:

- MS Access requires `as` for table aliases.
- The `WHERE` clause should be an `ON` clause.
- The columns in the `GROUP BY` need to match the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.

Comment: That worked thanks you very much, buy may i ask a question please why instead of WHERE you used ON? what is that command ? havent seen it to be honest, everything i did was with where

Comment: The explicit `join` syntax uses `ON` and it has since the 1990's when it was put into the ANSI standard.  I wasn't aware the MS Access had an optional `on` clause.  The only other database that allows this is MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by all non-aggregated columns listed in the select list, i.e.:

```
SELECT E.ID, E.NAME, COUNT(D.SOCIAL_SECURITY) AS NUMBER_OF_DEPARTMENTS
FROM EMPLOYEE E
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D
ON D.SOCIAL_SECURITY=E.SOCIAL_SECURITY
GROUP BY E.ID, E.NAME;
```

and not on `SOCIAL_SECURITY` (you are using the `COUNT` aggregate on it)

Because `E.ID` and `E.NAME` are directly correlated, there will only be a single level of grouping.

Comment: Thank you, but i now get an error in FROM clause :(

Comment: It might have been @Gordon's point that you are using `WHERE` to `JOIN` - it should be `ON`.